# String manipulation with std::adjacent_find

Tags: c++, programming-challenge, strings, c++14

> For the given strings (not containing numbers), print their shortened
>   versions,  where each adjacent sequence of the same characters longer
>   than 2, change to an expression consisting of a sign and a number of
>   repetitions.

**Sample input:**

```
4
AAA
ABCDEF
CCCCCCDDDDDDD
ZZAACCCDDDDEEEEEE
```

**Sample output:**

```
A3
ABCDEF
C6D7
ZZAAC3D4E6
```

**My code:**

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstddef>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

std::string reduce(std::string const& word) {
    std::string result;
    for (auto it = word.cbegin(); true;) {
        auto curr = std::adjacent_find(it, word.cend(), std::not_equal_to<int>());
        auto dist = std::distance(it, curr) + (curr != word.cend());

        if (dist < 3) {
            result += std::string(dist, *it);
        } else {
            result += *it + std::to_string(dist);
        }

        if (curr == word.cend()) {
            break;
        }
        it = 1 + curr;
    }
    return result;
}

int main() {
    std::size_t tests;
    std::cin >> tests;
    while (tests--) {
        std::string word;
        std::cin >> word;
        std::cout << reduce(word) << "\n";
    }
}
```

How could I simplify or improve this code?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please see [_What to do when someone answers_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). I have rolled back Rev 4 → 3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First impressions: nicely presented code; good use of the appropriate standard library functions and classes.

A minor suggestion would be to change the name, given that `reduce` is a well-known concept in functional programming (and is a function in `<numeric>`).  Perhaps call it `compress`?

I'd suggest extracting the constant `3` to give it a meaningful name.

Can we eliminate the `break` with some reorganisation of the loop?  Perhaps by using `std::mismatch(it, it+1)` instead of `std::adjacent_find()`?  (I haven't fully thought that through; it might not be better.)

We can avoid constructing a new string here:

> ```
>         result += std::string(dist, *it);
> ```

by using the overload of `append()` that takes two iterators:

```
        result.append(dist, *it);
```

Answer (score 1):

A few things might be better, but you will need to measure if they actually help. (untested code)

The most costly thing in your program (except the I/O) is properly allocation for the strings. So to avoid continuous reallocation you could try

```
result.reserve(word.size());
```

and

```
constexpr int LargeBuffer { 4096 };
std::string word;
word.reserve(LargeBuffer); // reuse the buffer.
while (tests--) {
    std::cin >> word;
    std::cout << reduce(word) << "\n"; // this call might use NRVO
}
```

That might still trigger one allocation per word, so a more drastic rebuild could be

```
std::string& reduce(std::string const& word, std::string & result)
```

and

```
constexpr int LargeBuffer { 4096 };
std::string word, result;
word.reserve(LargeBuffer); // reuse the buffer.
result.reserve(LargeBuffer);
while (tests--) {
    std::cin >> word;
    result.clear(); // should not dealloc.
    std::cout << reduce(word, result) << "\n";
}
```

The strings will grow and keep their new size if the actual word is larger than expected.

The next most expensive should be the std::to_string

```
    if (dist < 3) {
        result.append(dist, *it); // from Toby's answer
    } else {
        result.append(*it);
        if (dist < 10) {
          result.append('0'+dist);
        } else {
          result.append(std::to_string(dist));  // hopefully we are saved here by short string optimisation
      }
    }
```

The change should work nicely for your example data, less so if the repeats randomly change between <10 and >= 10.